# Failed to load @generated/type-graphql using Vitest

Tags: vite, typegraphql, vitest

I'm trying to migrate from jest to **vitest** in a nodejs application. Using **type-graphql**, i'm not able to run the tests because of the generated files :
`Error: [vite-node] Failed to load @generated/type-graphql`

I tried playing with `vitest.config.ts` with no result.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globals: true,
    testTimeout: 25000,
    globalSetup: 'src/__tests__/global-setup.ts',
    setupFiles: ['src/__tests__/setup.ts'],
    include: ['**/*.test.ts'],
  },
});
```

Any idea of a solution for that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by manually specifying an alias in the Vitest config:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    alias: {
      "@generated/type-graphql": path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        "./node_modules/@generated/type-graphql"
      )
    },
    // ... Other options
  }
});
```

This opened up a whole bunch of other problems, but this got me over the first hump.